# Compare SQL date column with date

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Suppose I inserted the date column value as

```
 TO_DATE('06/08/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I want to compare this column `valid_till` in Golang as

```
_err := database.GetDbReadClient().Raw("SELECT * from base_configs  WHERE tenant = ? AND valid_till <= ?", tenant, time.Now()).Scan(&baseConfig).Error
```

`time.Now()` won't work. But I am not getting around how to go about it to compare dates.

Is my insertion in Postgres correct?
If so, what can I write instead of time.Now to compare it with `valid_till`column?

Comment: `time.Now().Format("02/01/2006")` ?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang parse strange date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939261/golang-parse-strange-date-format)

Comment: But why do I need to pass `02/01/2006` as a format instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`? Seems strange

Comment: It's a reference date used by the `time` package. https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants *"The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time: `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006` which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference time can be thought of as **01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700**"* i.e that specific time is chosen because of the neat sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 that can be discerned in it.

Comment: you would have to dig the mailing list and repository history to figure that out with certitude. My understanding is that it was preferred to a long table of symbols such as https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php

Comment: if you simply do a `valid until now` you could do `valid_till <= now()` directly in the query

Comment: @HalfWebDev is `SELECT * from base_configs tenant, base_factor` a typo? Or are you using `tenant` as an alias of `base_configs` and then joining `base_factor`? What are you actually selecting?

Comment: @Matteo Will calling now() as a function work in a SQL string?

Comment: The ANSI SQL date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, same as ISO8601. Just use that instead of date formatting functions.

Comment: @HalfWebDev absolutely (just give it a try) See also the docs for further helpful functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could cast the parameter to the `date` type in the raw SQL.

```golang
raw := `SELECT * FROM base_configs
WHERE tenant = ?
AND valid_till <= ?::date`

err := database.GetDbReadClient().Raw(raw, tenant, time.Now()).Scan(&baseConfig).Error
```

Or just format the `time.Time` instance as a date `string`.

```golang
raw := `SELECT * FROM base_configs
WHERE tenant = ?
AND valid_till <= ?`

date := time.Now().Format("02/01/2006")
err := database.GetDbReadClient().Raw(raw, tenant, date).Scan(&baseConfig).Error
```

Comment: Okay. what impact does `$2::date` has? As the value stored is already a timestamp. No?

Comment: `$2::date` casts whatever value was passed in as `$2` to the `date` type. It's the same as if you did `CAST($2 AS date)`. See [Type Casts](https://postgresql.org/docs/13/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).

Comment: When I run query with dollar syntax, it gives me an error.  `expected 2 arguments, got 0; expected 2 arguments, got 0
[12.366ms] [rows:-] SELECT * FROM base_configs
                WHERE tenant = $1$
                AND valid_till <= $2$`

Comment: @HalfWebDev show the code that causes that error, show how you're invoking `Raw` and what arguments you're passing to it. But please don't post large code snippets in comments, instead post the code on play.golang.org or some other snippet sharing site.

Comment: Nothing much change there. Just replaced `?` with `$`. You can refer the same raw query as in OP. Plus, I didn't post snippet but full error.

Comment: @HalfWebDev Ok so it seems to be a gorm specific feature/bug. Postgres by default uses dollar sign placeholders, question mark placeholders are used by mysql and sqlite dialects, I belive, and gorm seems to prefer that. So just change the dollar signs back to question marks and it should work. https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4307#issuecomment-844129524

Comment: Yes, please update your answer to indicate the same